# AngularJS, Should I always check for undefined bound value?

Tags: angularjs, validation, exception, undefined

If my components using data from other components (data binding), is it necessary to always check for undefined?

Since I always expect data to come through. If it doesn't should I just let it crash and wait for data to be fixed, or should I check and handle the exception peacefully ?

I'd prefer checking but I want to know which is the best practice.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular will hide "undefined" values but you might want to look into using ng-cloak to use CSS to hide the elements until angular has had a chance to process any directives (or in some cases explicitly use ng-hide or ng-if to conditionally hide/remove elements depending on what has loaded).  So answer is in most cases no you don't need to check for it in bindings but yes you'll have to decide how the view should look while data or other things are loading.

```js
(function(){
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', function($timeout){
      var ctrl = this;
      ctrl.model = {
        testA: 12,
        testB: undefined
      }
      
      $timeout(function(){
        ctrl.model.testB = "something here now"
      }, 5000)
      
    })
})();
```

```css
pre{
background:yellow;
}

/*
Guarantees the elements aren't shown if they have ng-cloak
attribute, angular will remove this once it has processed the
directives on the element, at this point ng-if can take over
conditionally removing/adding the element or ng-hide can conditionally
remove it from display with css*/
[ng-cloak]{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
  <div>
    {{ctrl.model.testA}} <span ng-if="ctrl.model.testB" ng-cloak>-</span> {{ctrl.model.testB}}
  </div>
  
  <pre>{{ctrl|json}}</pre>
</div>
```

For general best practices just search angular best practices (or style guide) there are a few out there but John Papa's is the defacto standard for most people/places https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Comment: Thank you!! Especially JohnPapa link. Lots of useful tips.

Comment: @concuagia no problem if this answers the question just hit the check next to the answer so others who find this know it works... and I get my precious points :)  (if not, please let me know what's not working so I can correct the answer).